# I cant find the 20% of the total of multiple numbers

Tags: c++

```
    This line is the problem please help me :<

    cout<<"20% VAT:"<<(order_of_fries*pricef)+(order_of_burgers*priceb)+(order_of_donuts*priced)+(order_of_ice_cream*pricei)+(order_of_soft_drinks*prices)*0.20<<endl;
    
    pls help me get 20% :<<<
```

it doesn't work with 0.20 what else can I try?

Comment: Are you sure that only the last summand should be multiplied by 0.2?

Comment: I need to total all the things then multiply by 0.2 and I don't know how to total all then multiply

Comment: try breaking this into multiple lines and you should see where the issue is

Answer (score 1):

In `c++` we have the same rule as in the real world, that multiplication is resolved before addition. So you have to put the result of the sum in brackets:

```
cout<<"20% VAT:"<<((order_of_fries*pricef)
                  +(order_of_burgers*priceb)
                  +(order_of_donuts*priced)
                  +(order_of_ice_cream*pricei)
                  +(order_of_soft_drinks*prices))*0.20<<endl;
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU. YOU ARE A LIFE SAVER

Answer (score 0):

use

((order_of_fries*pricef)+(order_of_burgers*priceb)+(order_of_donuts*priced)+(order_of_ice_cream*pricei)+(order_of_soft_drinks*prices)) * 0.20

if you don't add all of the values together in parenthesis, then only the last value will be multiplied by 0.20 because multiplication comes before addition when following PEMDAS